# DiagramObject interface, method Update() not working

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I have some problem with `Update()` method, calling on the `EA.DiagramObject` object. I want to change the coordinates of `win32` control on the diagram. When buttons, checkboxes, etc. are inside diagram it works properly. But when this controls are inside another - `win32Dialog` it doesn't work. I'm setting values by making changes on the fields (left, right, top, bottom).
When the controls are placed in diagram (aren't child of other control), after calling method `Update()` and diagram reloading, everything works - controls changes its coordinates.
When controls are placed in win32Dialog, new values of control coordinates are as expected only before calling `Update()`. After calling method, values of margins are the same for left and right (e.g. 10) and top and bottom (e.g. 40), but it shouldn't. In eap file, coordinates of all of child controls are set to the win32Dialog top-left coordinate - (should be different).
I observed - when using debugging mode - that, calling method, change this values (only when controls are placed in win32Dialog. Placing controls inside win32DIalog is necessary for my program).

Project for tested this problem:

```
public class Program
{
    private EA.Diagram MyDiagram;
    private EA.Repository repository = null;

    private void Resize()
    {
        if (repository == null)
        {
            repository = new EA.Repository();
            repository.OpenFile("d:\\eatest.eap");
        }
        MyDiagram = GetDiagram(repository);

        for (short iDO = 0; iDO < MyDiagram.DiagramObjects.Count; iDO++)
        {
            EA.DiagramObject diagramObject = (EA.DiagramObject)MyDiagram.DiagramObjects.GetAt(iDO);
            var a = repository.GetElementByID(diagramObject.ElementID);

            Console.WriteLine(a.Stereotype);
            Console.WriteLine("\nBefore update: ");
            Console.WriteLine("left: " + diagramObject.left + " right: " + diagramObject.right + " top: " + diagramObject.top + " bottom: " + diagramObject.bottom);

            diagramObject.right += 50;
            diagramObject.bottom += 50;

            Console.WriteLine("\nAfter resizing:");
            Console.WriteLine("left: " + diagramObject.left + " right: " + diagramObject.right + " top: " + diagramObject.top + " bottom: " + diagramObject.bottom);

            diagramObject.Update();

            Console.WriteLine("\nAfter update: ");
            Console.WriteLine("left: " + diagramObject.left + " right: " + diagramObject.right + " top: " + diagramObject.top + " bottom: " + diagramObject.bottom);

            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        repository.ReloadDiagram(MyDiagram.DiagramID);
    }

    public static EA.Diagram GetDiagram(EA.Repository m_Repository)
    {
        EA.Package MyModel = (EA.Package)m_Repository.Models.GetAt(0);
        for (short iPackage = 0; iPackage < MyModel.Packages.Count; iPackage++)
        {
            EA.Package MyPackage = (EA.Package)MyModel.Packages.GetAt(iPackage);

            for (short iDiagram = 0; iDiagram < MyPackage.Diagrams.Count; iDiagram++)
            {
                var a = (EA.Diagram)MyPackage.Diagrams.GetAt(iDiagram);
                return (EA.Diagram)MyPackage.Diagrams.GetAt(iDiagram);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prog = new Program();
        prog.Resize();
    }
}
```

In line 19. is definied path to the EA project. Project should have one win32Dialog and win32controls inside.
Program, on the system console, will show:

- Type of control (win32Dialog, button, etc)
- values of margins (left, right, top, bottom) get from eap
- values of margins after resizing
- values of margins after calling Update().

Can you help me?

P.S. I'm using 2.10.0.0 version of EAInterop dll.

P.S2. I have also started conversation in Sparx forum: http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1409915245/0#0